# How do I store and retrieve friend roles in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, clojure, authorization

I'm not sure how to store `Friend` roles in a database. I can either store the string `"#{::user}"` or store `"user"` and transform it on retrieval. The former is bad juju and I'm unsure how to do the latter without making angels cry.

```
(ns foo.handler
  (:require [cemerick.friend :as friend]
        (cemerick.friend [workflows :as workflows]
                         [credentials :as creds])))

;; A dummy in-memory user "database"
(def users {"root" {:username "root"
                    :password (creds/hash-bcrypt "admin")
                    :roles #{::admin}}
            "jane" {:username "jane"
                    :password (creds/hash-bcrypt "pw")
                    :roles #{::user}}})

(derive ::admin ::user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm currently doing it; I'm sure it's all sorts of bad. Someone please stop me. Starting with `"user"` extracted from the database:

```
foo.handler> #{(keyword (str *ns* "/" "user"))}
=> #{:foo.handler/user}
```

Comment: That works, but maybe for more error handling and clarity you can define a map from your strings you store in the database to the roles you have in your friend app. like this {"user" :foo.handler/user "admin" :foo.handler/admin ...} and use it to get the right role for the string.